# SQL Server, table on accepts certain times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create constraints for store opening and closing times, for opening I want it after 9am and for closing I want it before 9pm, how can I implement this with TIMESTAMP. thank you.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[toyStoreManagement].[dbo].[TOY_STORE]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [toyStoreManagement].[dbo].[TOY_STORE]
GO
-- Create the table in the specified schema
CREATE TABLE [toyStoreManagement].[dbo].[TOY_STORE]
(
    [TOY_STORE_ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- Primary Key column
    [TOY_STORE_NAME] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [CITY] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    [PHONENUMBER] NUMERIC(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE(PHONENUMBER),
    [STORE_OPENING_TIME] TIMESTAMP (***HERE***) ,
    [STORE_CLOSING_TIME] TIMESTAMP (***AND HERE***)
    -- Specify more columns here
);
GO
```

Comment: Pardon me, but Oracle and SQL Server are two different databases. Do you want an answer for both databases?

Comment: I am sorry very new to this I am using MSSQL in azure data studio

Comment: for SQL Server you should not use timestamp, use time, datetime or datetime2 instead. Timestamp is depreciated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Don't need a high level of accuracy - smalldatetime works for such attributes. Logically a store's operating hours vary by date (and day of week) in most places, so you should consider storing this information in a separate table.

Comment: And don't develop bad habits. Firstly, your connection should determine the database to use for object references. Use 3 or 4 part names ONLY when you have a good reason. Not here.

Comment: I would try other methods but the assignment states to do it this way and check for store hours inserted in to the table using timestamp and the constraint I mentioned I'm am trying to achieve

Comment: You cannot do this with TIMESTAMP as that is just a numeric counter, set based on when the row was last written, and has no relationship with times of day. The datatype for a time of day is TIME

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP` is not what you think it is.  You want `TIME` columns with a `CHECK` constraint:

```
STORE_OPENING_TIME TIME,
STORE_CLOSING_TIME TIME,
CHECK (STORE_OPENING_TIME >= '09:00'00' AND STORE_CLOSING_TIME <= '21:00:00')
```